# Working On Android Studio - Maps In Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, keytool, android-keystore

Good day, I just would like to ask **how can I get my Md5/Sha1 code for android maps.** I'm doing my tutorial-studies and I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 as my default OS .

**Is there any terminal code for this?** to open up the keytool?

I found/arrived with this documentation in android dev - [dev.android signing your app](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)
but I'm stuck, I mean I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal and type the following

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

You can look at the android guide in [Displaying the debug certificate fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en)